# How do I get different results depending on 1 or 0 in field?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a table set up with a column titled has_sub which contains a tinyint value of 1 or 0 depending on whether the subcategory has another level or not. 1 = has another level and 0 = no other level.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get my anchors hrefs to change depending on the has_sub field (please see the following code)

```
$dbc = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
$sdb = mysql_select_db($db_database);

$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);

$query = "SELECT subcategory_name, has_sub FROM subcategories WHERE subcategory_parent = '$category'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
or die (mysql_error($dbc));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$subcatname = $row["subcategory_name"];
$hassub = $row["has_sub"];

if($hassub=='1')
echo "<li><a href='getsubsubs.php?category=$subcatname'>$subcatname</a></li>";

else
echo "<li><a href='listings.php?category=$subcatname'>$subcatname</a></li>";

}
```

As I am a beginner, chances are that I am missing something quite basic but can't seem to figure it out. I have been looking through the documentation to no avail. Many thanks in advance.

**Result of print_r($row):** (from OP comment)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Alarm Systems 
    [subcategory_name] => Alarm Systems 
    [1] => 0 
    [has_sub] => 0 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => Building Interiors and Services 
    [subcategory_name] => Building Interiors and Services 
    [1] => 1 
    [has_sub] => 1 
)
```

Comment: What output are you getting now?(for instance, only anchors that point to the listings.php? Or are the anchors not showing at all?)Analyzing the problem is always the fastest way to an answer. ;)

Comment: @Qqwy Only anchors pointing to listings.php appear.

Comment: What does an `echo $hassub;` give?

Comment: @M42 Nothing, blank page. It should echo a number if there is one stored right?

Comment: @RichardBell: Yes it should. Try with `print_r($row)` just after the `while`.

Comment: @M42 Thanks for your time. As a sample it prints: Array ( [0] => Alarm Systems [subcategory_name] => Alarm Systems [1] => 0 [has_sub] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => Building Interiors and Services [subcategory_name] => Building Interiors and Services [1] => 1 [has_sub] => 1 )

Comment: Are you getting any error? Could you post the error message as well? And the results of print_r that you posted, are those for all rows in the while loop?

Comment: @Nonym No, I do not get any error message.

Comment: @Nonym Yes all rows but just a sample of the arrays as there are so many.

Comment: @M42 Just ran through the test procedure of echo `$hassub;` and I think I cocked up the first time. This time when I tried I got a series of zeros with no number ones in there, yet the 1's appear in the array results from `print_r($row)`.

Comment: So sorry everyone I have been wasting your time. The error was at the database level. An input error on my behalf. Thank you very much for teaching me some trouble shooting techniques however. I have learnt a lot today :0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct so check input on the database for errors.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `if($hassub == 1)` instead of `if($hassub=='1')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few minor errors in the if-else statement. You have the right idea, just a few of the characters need to be changed because the format you have arranged it in, is causing it to be recognized as something it is not. Another thing that would make everything a whole heck of a lot more organized, would be if you would pack everything that is in the if-else statement into a variable rather than just echoing it out.

Instead of:

```
if($hassub=='1')
echo "<li><a href='getsubsubs.php?category=$subcatname'>$subcatname</a></li>";

else
echo "<li><a href='listings.php?category=$subcatname'>$subcatname</a></li>";
```

Use Something like this:

```
if ($hassub == "1") {
$hassub_toggle = '<li><a href="getsubsubs.php?category=' . $subcatname . '">' . $subcatname . '</a></li>';
}

else {
$hassub_toggle = '<li><a href="listings.php?category=' . $subcatname . '">' . $subcatname . '</a></li>';
}
```

Now wherever you put the

```
<?php echo $hassub_toggle; ?>
```

You will get your result. I personally like putting things into variables in that fashion because it makes things very organized and it enables you to apply more things to your return before you echo it onto your page.